# Dependencies for xlsx.js when using browser for parsing excel files in client mode

Tags: requirejs, client-side

I have included xlsx.js and jszip.js files in my javascript project and I'm calling them as follows
I'm not sure what files need to be included to avoid these errors. I realized there was a need for requireJS, I've got that included...

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ux/xlsxParser/require.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ux/jszip/jszip.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/ux/xlsxParser/xlsx.js"></script>
```

I call the reader in the following manner and it seems to fail with a lot of undefined errors.

```
            if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
            var workbook = XLSX.readFile(file);
            var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
            sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y) {
              var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[y];
              for (z in worksheet) {
                if(z[0] === '!') continue;
                console.log(y + "!" + z + "=" + JSON.stringify(worksheet[z].v));
              }
            });
```

Issues such as _fs is undefined, exports is undefined, modules is undefined etc.

I'm currently executing this in browser mode and I'm not sure if there are any more files/dependencies that need to be added to get this working. 
The code was downloaded from https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Any help here would be really great...Would love to see a working example if there are any sources. The examples I searched did not mention anything about the dependencies or files that need to go with this.

FYI: I don't use node.js

Comment: Did you try removing require.js?  [The demo page](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/index.html#L34-L35) does not use require.js

Comment: I'm having the same issue. did you find a solution? is so can you share it please